# How to get equivalent of "User name" using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to get the same value from Microsoft Graph that the Azure Portal displays as the user name (as shown below):

[image]

`userPrincipalName` is close, but for guest users it has the #EXT and underscore encoding (e.g., jim.oneil_outlook.com#EXT#@redacted.onmicrosoft.com).

`mail` is NOT populated for member users, so I can't rely on that, although it seems to be what I want for guests.

To make matters worse, we do have a *member* user that also has a EXT address (where `mail` is *not* populated and `userPrincipalName` is encoded), so simply using one or the other property based on member type isn't correct either. Decoding and parsing the `userPrincipalName` seems brittle and kludgy to me.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the same value from Microsoft Graph that the Azure Portal displays as the user name.

According to [user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user#properties) object, there is **no** equivalent of "user name" using Microsoft Graph Microsoft Graph.

> Decoding and parsing the userPrincipalName seems brittle and kludgy to me.

I don't why decoding and parsing the userPrincipalName seems brittle and kludgy to you. Indeed it is a way to get the "User name". And we could do that easily.

If C# code is possible, you could refer to the following code.

```
if (userPrincipalName.Contains("#EXT#"))
 {
      userName = user.UserPrincipalName.Substring(0, userPrincipalName.IndexOf("#")).Replace('_', '@');
 }
 else
 {
    userName = user.UserPrincipalName;
 }
```

The following is the whole demo code

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}";
string tenantId = "tenant Id";
string clientId = "clientId";
string secret = "scret key";
authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                requestMessage =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

 var displayName = "xxxx";
 var users = graphserviceClient.Users.Request().Select(x =>new 
 {
     x.UserPrincipalName,
     x.DisplayName

 } ).Filter("DisplayName eq '" + displayName + "'").GetAsync().Result;
 var user = users.FirstOrDefault();
 string userName = string.Empty;
 string userPrincipalName = user.UserPrincipalName;
 if (userPrincipalName.Contains("#EXT#"))
 {
      userName = user.UserPrincipalName.Substring(0, userPrincipalName.IndexOf("#")).Replace('_', '@');
 }
 else
 {
    userName = user.UserPrincipalName;
 }
```

Comment: anything that has magic strings like #EXT# is brittle and kludgy, IMHO.  True it's unlikely these will ever change, but this encoding is not something ideally I should not have to deal with.

Comment: I realize you intended this just as a sample, but wanted to point out that this code would still fail for an e-mail like jim_oneil@outlook.com.  That could be fixed as well, but are there other scenarios of the encoding that might not be obvious?

Comment: Yes, just the sample code. But as I mentioned that currently there is **no** such property for the User object. We need to add our logic to deal with the propertis . I captured the network from azure portal and  found that there is a property "`displayUserPrincipalName`". It seems stands for "User name" in the Azure portal. But I can't find it in the Microsoft User object.  I recommand that you could give your [good idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, You want retrieve username. However, Microsoft Graph only provides `MailNickName`, `UserPrincipalName`, and `mail`.

Based on my test, we can only get the user name through `UserPrincipalName` for this case.

Although some users have EXT in their email address, they do not contain `#`. So we can exclude those users that exist by parsing `userPrincipalName` whether or not to include `#`.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample you are referring to the B2B users in Azure AD.  B2B users are different in Azure AD, as you have noted in your question. In Azure AD, a B2B user, has a userType property value set to "*Guest*" - whereas local account to the tenant are set to "*Managed*".  So you could have some logic that checks for the userType, for example in the graph, to view all those B2B users one could do a `GET` to the following endpoint  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType eq 'Guest'`. Then you could also do an `if statement` something like

```
var logonName = "";  # holder for the logon name of the user
if(user.userType === 'Guest'){
  logonName = user.mail
} 
else {
  logonName = user.userPrincipalName
}
```

In short, the B2B users, you would want the `user.mail` attribute for that information.

Comment: Yes, I alluded to that in the question, but the userPrincipalName then needs some decoding, which I can do but feel I should not have to.

Comment: That's part of the B2B architecture at this time. Since the Guest user is really nothing more than a pointer to that user's primary tenant's account. This might be good to leave as a suggestion to the [user voice page](https://feedback.azure.com) for Azure AD itself?  Essentially, the concern is based on the architecture on the Azure AD B2B User types, and how then to correctly display that information in a universal format between B2B and Managed user.  Some good documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/user-properties)