# How to read username(DisplayUserPrincipalName) from Azure AD B2C using graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to read username from Azure AD for a logged-in user using Microsoft Graph API, but I am getting only Name and UserPrincipalName which is some kind of {Guid}-@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com. Below is my code snippet.

appsetting.json file

```
"Authentication": {
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "************",
    "ClientId": "********",
    "Tenant": "********",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "",
    "RedirectUri": "/signin-oidc",
    "ClientSecret": "*************"
  }
}
```

```
public class AzureADProfileResponse
  {
      public string userPrincipalName { get; set; }
      public string surname { get; set; }
      public string displayName { get; set; }
      public string givenName { get; set; }
  }
```

Get Token for Graph API

```
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
      {
          var clientId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:AzureAdB2C:ClientId");            
          var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).Build();
          var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
          string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" }; 
          string token = null;
          var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
          token = authResult.AccessToken;
          return token;
      }
```

Reading the config

```
      private AzureTenant GetTenantDetailsFromConfig()
      {
          return new AzureTenant
          {
              Tenant = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:AzureAdB2C:Tenant"),
              ClientId = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:AzureAdB2C:ClientId"),
              ClientSecret = _configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:AzureAdB2C:ClientSecret")
          };
      }
```

Getting profile details for logged-in user

````
      public async Task<AzureADProfileResponse> GetProfileDetails(AzureADProfileRequest azureAd)
      {
          var appValues = GetTenantDetailsFromConfig();
          string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + "/users" + "/" + azureAd.UserId ;


          var accessToken = GetAzureToken(appValues.ClientId, appValues.ClientSecret, appValues.Tenant).Result;

          using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
          {
              using (HttpRequestMessage apiRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
              {
                  apiRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                  using (HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(apiRequest).Result)
                  {
                      var apiJsonResponse = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                      return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureADProfileResponse>(apiJsonResponse);
                  }
              }
          }
      }```

I am getting the other details and able to get UserPrincipalName which is in Guid format, but I require to read the username which is displayed in Azure AD for each of the users. Is there any way by which I can decode/read the displayUserPrincipal name for the logged-in user.

I am able to see the response under network tab in Azure AD for the below request https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/Users/{objectId} with the displayUserPrincipalName.
````

Answer (score 4):

I was getting a `[GUID]@[tenant].onmicrosoft.com` userPrincipalName, and was looking for the user's actual email address.

I was able to find it in the identities array, which you have to query specifically for in the graph api. It has a convenient `signInType: 'emailAddress'` attribute so you can easily find it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the beta endpoint. The username is in the identities collection.

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft Graph only provides MailNickName, UserPrincipalName, and mail.

Please refer the supported/list of Properties returned from Users List in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

You can get the UserPrincipalName with the below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/userid?$select=userPrincipalName
```

Please refer similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903113/how-to-get-equivalent-of-user-name-using-microsoft-graph)

Comment: I tried this but it's not returning the displayUserPrincipalName instead it is returning {Guid}-@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com